# Google Ads conversion tracking in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

I need to add Google Ads conversion tracking to the thank you page in Shopware 6.
From what I can see, I need to expand the finish-details.html.twig file and add the Google Ads conversion code here.
But I can't seem to figure out how to get the order amount. Any suggestions?